# Function parameters and taking Int - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my function it takes two numbers that are Ints I want the First to take a variable and the Second to always be set to 100 here is a screenshot of my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2i9up898zi4p94/Screenshot%202014-10-16%2012.52.09.png?dl=0

```
var firstStep2 = calculatedAnswer / 1
var secondStep2 = "\(firstStep2 * 10 * 10)"

answerLabel.text = "\(secondStep2)"
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int)
  {  }
```

When I call this fraction this is what I put in.

```
printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: 535, Denominator: 100);
```

When I call this function I want the Denominator to be always be 100 and the numerator secondStep2 so if secondStep2 = 678

```
printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: secondStep2 a.k.a 678, Denominator: is always 100);
```

**Question:**
I want my function to take a variable and have the denominator always set to 100

**Simplifying Function**

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator = 100)
    {
        var finalNumerator = numerator;
        var finalDenominator = denominator;

        var wholeNumbers:Int = numerator / denominator;
        var remainder:Int = numerator % denominator;

        //println("wholeNumbers = \(wholeNumbers), remainder = \(remainder)");
        //println("\(denominator) % \(remainder) = \(denominator % remainder)");

        if(remainder > 0)
        {
            // see if we can simply the fraction part as well
            if(denominator % remainder == 0) // no remainder means remainder can be simplified further
            {
                finalDenominator = denominator / remainder;
                finalNumerator = remainder / remainder;
            }
            else
            {
                finalNumerator = remainder;
                finalDenominator = denominator;
            }
        }

        if(wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder > 0)
        {
            // prints out whole number and fraction parts
            println("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers) \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)");
        }
        else if (wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder == 0)
        {
            // prints out whole number only
            println("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers)");
        }
        else
        {
            // prints out fraction part only
            println("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's my understanding that you are looking for someone to write the function for you - if I'm right, than I don't think you'll have any answer. If you have problems with your code, we can help fixing errors, but stack overflow is not the right place to look for code writing

Comment: Why pass it as a parameter at all if you always want it to be 100? I don't understand the point of having it variable if you don't want it to be variable?

Comment: Hi @Antonio I'm a really big fan of yours and I read the developer's corner every morning. I'm not trying to get someone to write the code for me. I don't know how to change the function so it is always set to 100

Comment: In that case post your function in your question (no external screenshots, just code), so we can look at it and give proper suggestions

Comment: I think he wants to basically have a default value/optional parameter for his function. In that case though, you would either want to call the function without a second parameter, or write a second function that doesn't include the parameter, etc. I'm also not sure why it would even matter if you're in control of the function call (you could just pass 100 yourself ...)

Comment: I want the user to put their own numerator and have the denominator always stay the same

Comment: @Antonio updated the question so it has the function

Comment: So if the user inputs `a/b` then you want to find a numerator `c` such that `a/b == c/100` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I caught it correctly, you want your function taking 2 parameters to also be called with the first parameter only, assigning a default value to the 2nd.

**Solution #1**

In that case, your function signature should look like this:

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int = 100)
```

**Solution #2**

Alternatively, you can define the function without a default value for the 2nd parameter:

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int)
```

and add an overload with one parameter only:

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int) {
    printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: numerator, Denominator: 100)
}
```

---

In both cases, you can call the function with one parameter:

```
printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: 10)
```

and the `denominator` parameter will default to 100, or make it explicit, if you need a denominator different than 100:

```
printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: 10, Denominator: 77)
```

Comment: So what you are saying, is all I have to change my code so it is denominator: Int = 100

Comment: When declaring a function you always have to specify the parameter type, even if you assign a default value - type inference doesn't work in that case (if that's the reason why you omitted the type)

Comment: So when I call the function do I enter **printSimpliedFraction(Numerator: secondStep2, Denominator: 100)**?

Comment: can I also give Numerator: a variable like so, printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: secondStep2) or do i have to do that separately?

Comment: I suggest to try that yourself - btw yes, that works, as long as the type of the variable you are passing in is of the same type expected by the function (i.e. an `Int`)

Comment: Can I also make it a double?

Comment: You could create another function accepting doubles instead of ints, or make use of [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_275), but that is probably a little more complicated. Feel free to experiment though